# Is there a NULL statement in Swift?

Tags: swift, switch-statement

Compiler complain about the lack of at least one executable statement on `case` label in a `switch` :

```
switch someData {
   case .one:
      // No statements
      // Error occurs here

   case .two:
      // Some statements here

   default:
      // Some statements here
}
```

Here is the exact message:
`'case' label in a 'switch' should have at least one executable statement`

So is there any statement that do nothing to satisfy compiler requirement?
I know a simple statement like `print()` can do the job but I wonder if there is a specific one?

In other language, *Ada* for example there is a `null`statement to achieve this.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight
This is the exact answer, thank you.

Comment: or you could simply add break

Comment: @DanielGalasko
Yes, adding a `break` is the answer. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Set `break` or `return`, depending on what you want to do.

```
switch someData {
case .one:
   nil

case .two:
  // Some statements here

default:
  // Some statements here
}
```

Comment: The question concerned the first `case`: .one

Comment: `nil` gives a compiler error (at least when I try it), and `return` returns from the enclosing *function* and is therefore fundamentally different from `break`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Actually, in my opinion his question is not well formulated because there no point set `break` to a `case` which you aren't going to use. Just don't include it in the `switch` statement at all.

Comment: @CeceXX: That is not true. If you *omit* `case .one` than that value will be handled in the `default` case which might not be what you want.